# 'active' class issue in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i have a menu like

```
           <ul class="nav nav-list">
                @for (int i = 1; i <= pageno; i++)
                {
                    <li> <a href="~/Insts?page=@i&count=10">@i</a></li>
                }
            </ul>
```

i want to add the active class when clicking on the link . for that i am using the following code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav li a').click(function (e) {

        $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        if (!$parent.hasClass('active')) {
            $parent.addClass('active');
        }
        return false;
    });
  });
```

by using this active class is added. but link is not going to particular path. if `return false` is not added, then links are worked but `active` `class` is not worked.

Comment: just wondering why do you wanna add an active class when you wanna redirect the user to another location?

Comment: @Shyama when you return false it's preventing the default action of the link , That's y the link is not working . If you remove the return false the link will take you to the URL mentiond.

Comment: @Midhun: but that time active class is not added

Comment: @shayama that time the new page will be loading in the browser right ?

Comment: @Midhun: yes, loading

Comment: Your code is fine , Actually your are not seeing the changes as the new page is loading  that'all.

Comment: @Midhun: i am seeing, but i want that in stable, can u help that to find the solution for that

Comment: @shyama : what you mean by stable ? Excatly what's your problem??? If you want to see your code woking see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Midhun52/Lc7sc1ce/ , use mouseover event to check your code.

Answer (score 0):

Returning false in the event handler is similar to preventDefault() method in jquery. It's prevents the default action. So if you are returning the false to click event for the link then it's preventing the navigation action for the link.

You may use [MouseOver event](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) to add the class to the link .

so the code should be

> $(document).ready(function () {
>       $('.nav li a').mouseover(function (e) {
>
> ```
>     $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
>     var $parent = $(this).parent();
>     if (!$parent.hasClass('active')) {
>         $parent.addClass('active');
>     }
>
> });   });
> ```

Working demo at 
http://jsfiddle.net/Midhun52/Lc7sc1ce/